# (C#) How do I retrieve the Author / Comments Property from a Word or Excel File?

Tags: c#, file, properties, ms-office

I need to read the Comments in from a Excel or Word file... 
Any ideas?

I tried `FileVersionInfo` didn't seem to work.

I also tried using the Shell32 option, which did work. Just seems like the long way round...

Is there a quicker way?

Thanks

Comment: Use COM to fire up an instance of Excel or Word, and ask them? That's what the Shell is doing when you ask it...

Comment: Read answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509831/reading-data-from-doc-or-docx-and-inserting-into-db). Maybe will help.

Comment: You can find your solution in here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbinterop/thread/85d19939-4822-4a4a-8fba-8127b3807af2/

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the comments from Revisions? You can use [Document.Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.comments%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
Comments comments = yourwordDoc.Comments;
        foreach (var comment in comments)
        {
            var text = comment.Range.Text;


        }
```